# Apache Pig Latin using matches

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying with Apache Pig latin to FILTER url which matches particular pattern.

for ex:
**http://www.example.com/homePage.do?locale=en_US

I want to filter all the URL that matches

locale=en_US (or)
locale=en_CA

Please need help on resolving this.

Comment: Have you had a look into https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/func.html#regex-extract ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... I am new to Pig and please help me with an example with above sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `url matches '.*(locale=en_US|locale=en_CA).*'`

It is good also to look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html when using regex in Pig